# Show multiple images in interactive mode python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, image-processing, pytorch

I'm in an interactive program which marks specific part of an images through clicking the points around it. I want to show the segmented parts in a different image. it seems that plt.imshow(image) doesn't work well in an interactive environment and i cant turn it off cause then i cant work on the main image. Is there a better command to show an specific array in an interactive mode separately.

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're asking. Please specifiy your exact problem and underly your efforts with code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned `matplotlib`'s [interactive mode on](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ion.html)?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()  # turning on interactive mode
```

Comment: Its already turned on. Actually the problem is that i have to turn it off to print the second image.

Comment: @hamid.khb you can plot the image in a second figure, or use [`plt.subplot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html)